# Python Nested Loop Trouble

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a problem on my weekly lab that asks:

> Write a program that uses nested loops to collect data and calculate
>   the average temperature over a period of months. The program should
>   first ask for the number of months. The outer loop will iterate once
>   for each month. The inner loop will iterate FOUR times, once for each
>   week in a month. Each iteration of the inner loop will ask the user
>   for the average temperature of that week. After all iterations, the
>   program should display the average temperature for each month, and for
>   the entire period (for all the months).

This is the code I have come up with thus far:

```
def avgTemp():
    '''This function takes the input of number of months and takes 4 weekly temp averages
       for each month then prints out the whole average

       num_of_month --- integer
       week_temp --- integer
       total_avg --- return'''


    num_of_month = int(input("Number of Months?: ")) #Asks how many months

    total_avg = 0

    monthly_avg = 0

    for number in range(0,num_of_month):

        for week in range(0,4):

            week_temp = int(input("Avg week temp?: "))

            monthly_avg += week_temp

        monthly_avg = monthly_avg/4

        total_avg += monthly_avg

    total_avg = total_avg/num_of_month

    print (total_avg)
    print (monthly_avg)
```

I cannot seem to work out how to get it to display the monthly averages for each month. I would ideally use a list and just append the entries but because this is an intro class, we have not been "taught" lists yet and therefore can't use them. So, using the tools I have above, what suggestions do you have to get the output I want?

Comment: Have you reviewed your textbook, spoken with your instructor, discussed it with your classmates, and done some research on Google?

Comment: An ideal Stackoverflow question includes a MCVE (see [mcve]). In particular, please edit your post to include some sample inputs, the output you would expect, and the output you are actually getting. You might also benefit from reading [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

Put `print (monthly_avg)` inside your outer loop (the loop over the months).

Currently, you only print the last `monthly_avg`. Also, you need to reset the value of monthly_avg as you iterate over each month.

Comment: This certainly doesn't make OP's code actually work as they intend it to, but I'll admit it's a good start, and does "display the monthly averages for each month" rather than just once. They'll notice that they're not great averages, though!

Answer (score 0):

According to your specification, you must ask for all the values before printing the averages for each month.  You therefore need to store values for each month.

It is conceptually easier to store totals (hence the modified variables names).  Just perform the divisions before printing averages.

```
# Asks how many months
num_of_months = int(input("Number of Months?: "))
num_of_weeks = 4

# ask and store for weekly values
month_totals = [ 0 ] * num_of_weeks
total = 0
for month in range(num_of_months):
  for week in range(num_of_weeks):
    week_avg = int(input("Avg week temp?: "))
    month_totals[month] += week_avg
    total += week_avg

# print averages for each month
for month in range(num_of_months):
  month_avg = float(month_totals[month]) / float(num_of_weeks)
  print (month_avg)

# print average for the entire period
total_avg = float(total) / float(num_of_months * num_of_weeks)
print (total_avg)
```